# Why doesnt this javascript code generate any output? there doesnt seem to be any errors

Tags: javascript, html

Im learning javascript and i am stuck with this. there doesnt seem to be any syntax errors and the form displays correctly in html, im just not getting any of the calculated data. Im not sure if i am missing something small that you may notice or whether what i have written is completeley wrong. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

thanks for the help

**HTML:**

```
<form id="loanddata">
    <table>
        <tr><td><b>enter loan information</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>1) Amount of loan</td> <td><input type="text" name="principal" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2) Annual Percent of increase</td> <td><input type="text" name="interest" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>3) Repayment period in years</td><td><input type="text" name="years" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td>
            <td><button name="compute" type="submit" onclick="calculate();"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><b>Payment Information</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>4) Your Monthly Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="payment"></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>5)Your Total Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="total"></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>6) Your Total Interest Payment</td> <td><span class="result" id="totalinterest"></td>        </tr>

    </table>   
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function calculate() {    

var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
var interest = document.loandata.interest.value;
var payments = document.loandata.years.value;

var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
var total = document.getElementById("total");
var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");

if (isFinite(monthly)){

    payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
    totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);

    } else {
        payment.innerHTML = "";
        total.innerHTML = "";
        totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Typo, id is `loanddata` but you use `document.loandata` also for that syntax you must use `name` not `id`.

Comment: Have you checked console for any errors? Or just looking at code and checking?

Comment: im just lookin at it in dreamweaver which shows no errors.

thanks for pointing out the typo but i still have the same problem..

woohoo :D it worked when i changed id to name, thanks alot

Comment: Open the page in a browser, hit F12 and look in the console; it will display any errors. (for document.loandata to work the name attribute must be "loandata" it will not if its the id)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr><td><b>enter loan information</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>1) Amount of loan</td> <td><input type="text" id="principal" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
<tr><td>2) Annual Percent of increase</td> <td><input type="text" id="interest" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
<tr><td>3) Repayment period in years</td><td><input type="text" id="years" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td>
    <td><button name="compute" type="submit" onclick="calculate();" /></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><b>Payment Information</b></td></tr>

<tr><td>4) Your Monthly Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="payment"></span></td></tr>

<tr><td>5)Your Total Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="total"></span></td></tr>

<tr><td>6) Your Total Interest Payment</td> <td><span class="result" id="totalinterest"></td></tr>

</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function calculate() {    
var principal = parseInt(document.getElementById("principal").value);
var interest = parseInt(document.getElementById("interest").value);
var payments = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value);

if(!isNaN(principal) && !isNaN(interest) && !isNaN(payments)){

    var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
    var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);
    var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");

    if (isFinite(monthly)){

        payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
        total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
        totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);

        } else {
            payment.innerHTML = "";
            total.innerHTML = "";
            totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
        }   
    }
}
```

Working **[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/c6yva28m/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<form id="loanddata">
```

For:

```
<form name="loandata">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code.
There was some typo and also basic javascript errors.

- First form id will be loandata.
- Second access the form values like this-
  document.forms.loandata.principal.value;
- Last - Add this to restrict form submission-   onsubmit="return
  false;"

Here is the working code.

**HTML-**

```
<form id="loandata" onsubmit="return false;">

    <table>

        <tr><td><b>enter loan information</b></td></tr>

        <tr><td>1) Amount of loan</td> <td><input type="text" name="principal" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>2) Annual Percent of increase</td> <td><input type="text" name="interest" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>3) Repayment period in years</td><td><input type="text" name="years" onchange="calculate();"></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td><button name="compute" onclick="calculate();"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr><td><b>Payment Information</b></td></tr>

        <tr><td>4) Your Monthly Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="payment"></span></td></tr>

        <tr><td>5)Your Total Payment</td> <td>$<span class="result" id="total"></span></td></tr>

        <tr><td>6) Your Total Interest Payment</td> <td><span class="result" id="totalinterest"></td></tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

**JS-**

```
function calculate() {

        var principal = document.forms.loandata.principal.value;
        var interest = document.forms.loandata.interest.value;
        var payments = document.forms.loandata.years.value;

        var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
        var monthly = (principal * x * interest) / (x - 1);

        var payment = document.getElementById("payment");
        var total = document.getElementById("total");
        var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");

        if (isFinite(monthly)) {

            payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
            total.innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
            totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthly * payments) - principal).toFixed(2);

        } else {
            payment.innerHTML = "";
            total.innerHTML = "";
            totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
```

Make sure to attach the JS on Head tag.